# Transferring HTML documents with JSON responses. Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, parsing

recently i`ve faced a problem parsing JSON responses, that contains html injections.

```
 [{"Date":"\/Date(1316445326553+0400)\/",
 "Dishes":null,"Id":103,"Name":"Menutka уже с Вами!",
 "PictureId":130144,
 "TextHtml":"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-\/\/W3C\/\/DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional\/\/EN' 'http:\/\/www.w3.org\/TR\/xhtml1\/DTD\/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>\u000a<html xmlns='http:\/\/www.w3.org\/1999\/xhtml'>\u000a<head>\u000a... etc",
 "Type":1,"UserId":1,"UserName":"Администратор"}]
```

and tried to do `JSON.parse response.body` where response body is my JSON. It silenly obeys, but returns empty collection. I tried to validate this json on [this site](http://jsonlint.com/) and it says "It s valid"

So i`m a bit confused about whats gone wrong.

PS this is my parse method:

```
   def self.get(uri)
raw_url = BASE_URL+uri
url = "#{BASE_URL}"+CGI::escape(uri)
f = File.open('response.log', 'a')
start = Time.new
f.print "#{start.to_s}\t#{uri}"
resp = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url))
stop = Time.new
f.puts "\t\t#{stop-start} seconds"
f.close
data = resp.body
begin
  if data.blank? or data.include?('<html')
    return {}
  end
  object = JSON.parse(data)
rescue JSON::ParserError
  raise Exceptions::NothingReturned, "GET Error on #{raw_url}"
end
end
```

Comment: Could you post the code where you actually parse the JSON response?

Answer (score 0):

i'm not quite sure if it's that simple, but you're deliberately returning `{}` if your JSON contains a `<html` tag? what behavior do you want?

if you want to distinguish between html and json responses, just use the Content-Type response header

Comment: I`m having json response with the only html block in it.